# Multiple unsequenced modifications to 'a'，a = a++

Tags: c, objective-c

Why i can't do the following in Objective-C?

```
a = (a < 10) ? (a++) : a;
```

or

```
a = (a++)
```

[image]

Comment: Think very carefully about what `a = a++` does, step by step, and you'll find there's a bit of a conflict between two of the steps.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior/#30914692).

Comment: Thank you for the link.It's very helpful to me.Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The `++` in `a++` is a post-increment. In short, `a = a++` does the following:

```
int tmp = a; // get the value of a
a = a + 1 //post-increment a
a = tmp // do the assignment
```

As noted by others, in C this is actually **undefined behavior** and different compilers can order the operations differently.

Try to avoid using `++` and `--` operators when you can. The operators introduce side effects which are hard to read. Why not simply write:

```
if (a < 10) {
   a += 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added the annex to your answer instead of mine. Removed it.

Comment: `a = a++` in C is *undefined behaviour*. I have no Objective-C standard documentation, but I suspect that same holds for that language too. If that is the case, then your reasoning about the code does not hold, since *anything* can happen.

Comment: @user694733 I suspected the behavior was undefined but I wasn't sure because I am no C expert. I wanted to explain what happens in a way a junior would understand. I will add a bigger warning.

Comment: Indeed, you do not have to be an C expert to see that the assignment is meaningless. And moreover these are edge cases of C you usually do not need in Objective-C. It is more for incorporated C code.

Comment: @user694733 There is no Objective-C standard a all, but everybody expects that the C part of Objective-C conforms to the C standard. At least real-world compilers let you select the used C standard for compiling Objective-C sources …

Answer (score 6):

To extend Sulthan's answer, there are several problem with your expressions, at least the simple assignment (case 2).

A. There is no sense in doing so. Even `a++` has a value (is a non-void expression) that can be assigned, it automatically assigns the result to `a` itself. So the best you can expect is equivalent to

```
a++;
```

The assignment cannot improve the assignment at all. But this is not the error message.

B. Sulthans replacement of the statement is a better case. It is even worse: The `++` operator has the value of `a` (at the beginning of the expression) and the effect to increment `a` at *some point in future*: The increment can be delayed up to the next sequence point.

> The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between the previous and the next sequence point.

(ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.5.2.4, 2)

But the assignment operator `=` is *not* a sequence point (Annex C).

> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> *[Neither assignment operator nor `)` is included in the list]*

Therefore the expression can be replaced with what Sulthan said:

```
int tmp = a; // get the value of a
a = a + 1 //post-increment a
a = tmp // do the assignment
```

with the result, that `a` still contains the old value.

Or the expression can be replaced with this code …:

```
int tmp = a; // get the value of a
a = tmp // assignemnt
a = a + 1 // increment
```

… with a different result (`a` is incremented). This is what the error message says: There is no defined *sequence* (order the operations has to be applied.)

You can insert a sequence point using the comma operator `,` (what is the primary use of it), …

```
a++, a=a; // first increment, then assign
```

… but this shows the whole leak of meaning of what you want to do.

It is the same with your first example. Though `?` is a sequence point …:

> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> … The end of the first operand of the following operators: *[…]* conditional ? (6.5.15);*[…]*.

… both the increment (`a++`) and the assignment (`a=`) are after the `?` operator is evaluated and therefore unsequenced ("in random order") again.

To make the comment "Be careful" more concrete: Don't use an incremented object in an expression twice. (Unless there is a clear sequence point).

```
int a = 1;
… = a++ * a;
```

… evaluates to what? 2? 1? Undefined, because the increment can take place after reading `a` "the second time".

BTW: The Q is not related to Objective-C, but to pure C. There is no Objective-C influence to C in that point. I changed the tagging.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.It's helping me！